# Charge density and free electron density is not the same, right?

Tags: electric-current, charge

Charge density is the density of charges say for example that a piece of copper is charged then the charge density in that piece of copper is the total charge divided by the volume of that piece.
While the electron density for a neutral or a charged piece of copper is roughly the same, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free electrons in copper arise from the ionisation of copper atoms into positive copper ions through the loss of one (or more) electron. Strictly speaking, the charge density of copper metal would be zero, as even though there are free electrons, the negative charge of these is exactly balanced by the positive charge of the positive copper ions.

However, if one was to talk about the free charge density of neutral copper, that would be equivalent to the electron charge density, and therefore would be non-zero.

Yet, for a charged piece of copper, the charge density would clearly be non-zero as there is a net charge across the piece of copper.

Hope this clarifies things.